# formal adjoint of a vector fields

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators

Let $X=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}(x)\partial_{x_{j}}$ be a smooth vector fields defined on $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where  $\Omega\subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ is supposed to be a bounded open domain. Denote $X^{*}$ be the formal adjoint of $X$. I feel confused about the explicit formula about $X^{*}$. I get  $X^{*}=-X-\text{div}X$ , but I found some papers (i.e [Harnack estimates for degenerate parabolic equations modeled on the subelliptic p-Laplacian](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870814000693/1-s2.0-S0001870814000693-main.pdf?_tid=f27e2ad7-e54e-452f-ad61-bbe13083528d&acdnat=1529637172_4ff8d76a203cbeda44eb7755556c67c3)) said that $X^{*}=-X+\text{div}X$. I don't know which is correct. Here is my approach.
Let $u,v\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$, we have 
$$ (Xu,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}=(u,X^{*}v)_{L^2(\Omega)},$$
That is 
$$ \int_{\Omega}v\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}(x)\partial_{x_{j}}udx=(u,X^{*}v)_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$
Observe that 
\begin{align}
&\int_{\Omega}v\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}(x)\partial_{x_{j}}udx\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\Omega}\partial_{x_{j}}(a_{j}(x)uv)dx-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\Omega}u\cdot a_{j}(x)\partial_{x_{j}}vdx-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\Omega}uv\partial_{x_{j}}a_{j}(x)dx\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\Omega}\partial_{x_{j}}(a_{j}(x)uv)dx-\int_{\Omega}u\cdot Xv-\int_{\Omega}u\cdot \text{div}X\cdot v dx\\
&=\int_{\partial\Omega} uv\cdot X\cdot \overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}dS(x)-\int_{\Omega} u(X+\text{div}X)v dx
\end{align}
Here $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}$ is the outward normal vector of $\partial\Omega$.
Since $u,v\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$, we have 
$$\int_{\Omega}v\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}(x)\partial_{x_{j}}udx=-\int_{\Omega} u(X+\text{div}X)v dx$$
Which implies $$ (Xu,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}=(u,(-X-\text{div}X)v)_{L^2(\Omega)}$$.

On the other hand, I found in Wiki that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator
If we denote $P=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}(x)D^{\alpha}$ be the $k$ order differential operator, then the adjoint of $P$ should be 
$$ P^{*}u=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}(-1)^{|\alpha|}D^{\alpha}(a_{\alpha}(x)u)$$. In particular, when we choose $P=X$, we can also get above result. 
Is there exist any mistake in my approach? Can someone help me with it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your calculation is fine. When it doubt about things like this, why don't consider the $1D$-case? If $X= a(x) \partial_x$, then $X^*f=(a\partial_x)^*f = (\partial_x^*a^*)f=-\partial_x(af)=-af'-a'f=-Xf-\mathrm{div}X f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a difference in notation: some people take $\operatorname{div}{X}$ to be $-\sum_i \partial_{x_i}a_i$ so that the Laplacian $\operatorname{div}\operatorname{grad} \phi$ is a positive operator (the "geometrical" convention).